# Build an array from a dataframe based on a sliding window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns. I want to build an array from this dataframe. I want to use a `window` to move across the rows. I want to start from row 0 until end, and put the value of three columns in one row of array based on the column `b` in data frame.

For example, with window size of 3, I put the `1,2,3` which are the three value in the first window and in column `a` put with the three value in column `c`, `-1,1,5` and at the last column the value of column b is `1`. This process will contintue until the column `b` changed. Then, for the next value of column `b` we have the same process. Thank you in advance
Here is the dataframe which I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['a'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 1,2,3]
df ['b'] = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7]
df ['c'] = [-1,1,5,6,7,3,1,6,8,3,9,10,1]
df
```

```
     a  b   c
0    1  1  -1
1    2  1   1
2    3  1   5
3    4  1   6
4    5  2   7
5    6  2   3
6    7  2   1
7    8  2   6
8    9  7   8
9   10  7   3
10   1  7   9
11   2  7  10
12   3  7   1
```

The array which I want is:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3, -1,  1,  5,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  1,  5,  6,  1],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  7,  3,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  3,  1,  6,  2],
       [ 9, 10,  1,  8,  3,  9,  7],
       [10,  1,  2,  3,  9, 10,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  9, 10,  1,  7]])
```

I tried, but I think that I am far away from a solution.

```
w = 3

A = np.zeros((w,len(df)-w+1))

for i in range(len(df)-w+1):
    A[:,i] = df.iloc[i:w+i,0]

A = A.T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a `GroupBy.apply` and a bit of numpy:

```
# group by consecutive b
group = df['b'].diff().abs().gt(0).cumsum()
# or if simply groupby by 'b' overall (not consecutive)
# group = 'b'

def flatten_group(g):
    # pandas' rolling only aggregates, doing a custom rolling
    # that flattens the columns a & c and add the 1st value of b
    return [np.r_[g.iloc[i:i+3][['a', 'c']].to_numpy().ravel('F'),
                  [g['b'].iloc[0]]]
            for i in range(len(g)-2)]

# apply per group and stack as numpy array
a = np.vstack(df.groupby(group).apply(flatten_group).explode())
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3, -1,  1,  5,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  1,  5,  6,  1],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  7,  3,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  3,  1,  6,  2],
       [ 9, 10,  1,  8,  3,  9,  7],
       [10,  1,  2,  3,  9, 10,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  9, 10,  1,  7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
res = []
for n,g in df.groupby('b'):
    for r in g[['a','c']].rolling(3):
        if len(r)==3:
            res.append(r.T.values.ravel().tolist()+[n])

np.array(res)
'''
array([[ 1,  2,  3, -1,  1,  5,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  1,  5,  6,  1],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  7,  3,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  3,  1,  6,  2],
       [ 9, 10,  1,  8,  3,  9,  7],
       [10,  1,  2,  3,  9, 10,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  9, 10,  1,  7]])
```